# JavaFX8: How to shut down anti-aliasing on text?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm currently working on application in Java, using JavaFX. Window from program will be as stream on low-resolution LED screen. What I need is completely shut-down anti aliasing on all text within the window (label text, textarea, etc).

I've googled few times, tried CSS `-fx-smooth` and dig into documentation, still without success. My application is running on Windows 7 Pro 64bit, in system settings is antialiasing shut down, could someone point me to right direction?

Comment: I do not believe that what you ask is possible.

Comment: Thank you for response, I miss it. So there is no option for total disable of label anti aliasing?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to turn off the system property for smoothing fonts:

```
System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false");
```

Maybe take a look at: [How to force anti-aliasing in JavaFX fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254000/how-to-force-anti-aliasing-in-javafx-fonts)

Comment: Hello Tom! Thanks a lot for reply, yes I have tried that but it didnt help at all. And I read that topic you linked, but still without succes. I ve been little busy lately, but I will dig a deeper tommorow. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

While this question is one year old, I recently struggled with the same problem and didn't find a solution here. However, by tinkering around I found that the System properties "prism.lcdtext" and "prism.subpixeltext" are checked **before** the start(Stage) method is called. The work-around is therefore to set those properties in your public static void main(String[]), before the call to launch :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false");
    System.setProperty("prism.subpixeltext", "false");

    launch(args);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Are you aware of a way to apply the same effect to a WebView?