# JavaFX: Entirely turn off scene anti-aliasing (inclusive of control text anti-aliasing)

Tags: java, scala, javafx, scalafx, font-smoothing

Since both `System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false")` and `System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "true")` are unsatisfactory (the former appears downy whereas the latter appears colorful at the letter edges even though the text color is black; on my LCD it looks even uglier than reported here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131923),

**I prefer to turn off anti-aliasing entirely.**

The setting [`SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SceneAntialiasing.html) seems not to affect my buttons/lists/dropdowns/... (I guess it is meant for drawing only).

**How can I turn off anti-aliasing completely? I would like to use a font similar to those of Windows 2000 and the first version of Win XP, which work without anti-aliasing** (and besides save space because they can be scaled down more than have-to-be-smoothed fonts).

[UPDATE] Screenshot added (as requested)

The right window is generated by my ScalaFX app. Pure plain standard code, no setting applied.

(Playing with `System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false")` and `System.setProperty("prism.text", "t2k")` gives me slightly better, but still unsatisfactory results.)

See the enlarged 'W' and its many colors, which stems from the first button in the right window (JavaFX): for demanding users, this is intolerable. And please compare the smoothness of the monospace texts (left: Ubuntu, right: JavaFX).

[image: Comparison: left Ubuntu; right JavaFX]

Comment: add a minimal sample code & current issue observed(probably a screenshot) to get better answers & attention.

Comment: Which minimal sample code do you need? Please see my question: I am simply asking how I could turn off text anti-aliasing. Please either say "impossible" or post a short answer how anti-aliasing can be turned off. Tomorrow, I will post a screenshot but I guess it will be difficult to make anti-aliasing work correctly. Btw. it is just an ordinary JavaFX app written in ScalaFX.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot ??

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254000/how-to-force-anti-aliasing-in-javafx-fonts

Comment: Unfortunately not, that's why I posted my question with the intent of turning off font-smoothing. I guess the JavaFX world doesn't have font-smoothing under control. It is too difficult for them to handle. Hence turning it off is the only solution to the problem.