# What's wrong with JavaFX's WebView text?

Tags: java, javafx, webview, webkit

I'm experimenting with JavaFX's WebView that uses WebKit and there's something wrong with fonts. On Windows, a simple app I built looks like this:

[image]

But on MacOS it looks like this

[image]

Any ideas what's going on? What's wrong with JavaFX?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24419312/2512768) suggests that this is a CSS issue. Maybe see if that helps you.

Comment: @TW80000 that seems to be the issue with the lack of smoothness on Windows but not with the macOS one. Thank you. I'm going to modify my question accordingly.

Comment: No problem. Just a wild guess for macOS, but could it be that you're using a font that macOS doesn't have? The macOS font from your screenshot is much bigger. The missing glyphs problem is still very strange though.

Comment: The web site looks fine on Chrome on macOS so, even if the font is not present, the problem is JavaFX's WebView is not correctly falling back to other fonts like it should, like Chrome does.