# How can I disable antialiasing on a JavaFX Canvas?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, antialiasing

Currently I am working on a 2D Game using JavaFX, the game is pixel art.
Unfortunetly, the pixel art is blurry, caused by Antialiasing.

Is there any way to disable antialiasing on a JavaFX canvas?
I've tried using SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED and It didn't work.
I can't find any other way of disabling it.

Comment: Can you provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254000/how-to-force-anti-aliasing-in-javafx-fonts

Comment: @Matheus Marques I don't think the question you linked is related to this question.

Comment: @BlockFade did you fix this? Still no luck 4 years later !

Answer (score 4):

```
canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setImageSmoothing(false);
```

*(Since JavaFX 12).*